# Width of website not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, width

As you can see on this link ( http://riksblog.com/Marnik/index.html ), for some reason the width of the body and website is as it should, but there's a strange, empty space next to my website which makes it wider than it should.

I'm using bootstrap so I'm not really able to use these tricks like media-queries in css for the desktop version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this css:

```css
section.first .section-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 150px 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

which causes the `.section-content` div to be as wide as its parent plus 30px.

Possible solutions are to add a `box-sizing` property to the style

```
    box-sizing: border-box;
```

or change the width so that it doesn't exceed its parent

```
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
```

Comment: Hello Mr Lister, thank you for the insight. I see what the problem is and I managed to fix it using width: calc(100%-30px); Thank you for the help and solution.

Comment: @MarnikBruyndonckx OK. If this issue is solved, could you click the check mark next to the answer? That will let the system know the question has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

your looking for the overflow css property try this:

```
body {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

to completely remove the problem get rid of the right padding on this class:

```
section.first .section-content {
padding: 150px 15px //remove left/right padding
}
```

Comment: While this solutions hides the problem, it doesn't actually solve it. It will also hide the horizontal scrollbar when it is really needed (with narrow browser screens). A much better solution is to actually find the culprit and fix it.

Comment: @Kepoly OK. I also added a couple of solutions in my own answer.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks for pointing that out I shouldn't have went to my first instincts!